# Animate Add Border (grow then shrink)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a little effect without using any plugins/libraries besides jquery. The goal is to make it so that when the user changes the value of a box, a border appears, grows to 8px and then shrinks back to 0px. Right now I have the following shell of a code:

```
$('#pastebox').on('input', function() {
    $("#pastebox").css("border", "solid 1px green");
});
```

I know that I can animate using something like the following, but I'm having trouble getting it to work:

```
$("#pastebox").animate({border-width: '5px'}, 1000);
```

I know that if I could get the previous to work, I could then do something like:

```
$('#pastebox').on('input', function() {
    $("#pastebox").css("border", "solid 1px green");
    $("#pastebox").animate({border-width: '5px'}, 1000);
    $("#pastebox").animate({border-width: '0px'}, 1000);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object keys cannot contain a minus sign (`border-width`) - either camelCase it, or quote it:

```js
$('#pastebox').on('input', function() {
    $("#pastebox").css("border", "solid 1px green");
    $("#pastebox").animate({"border-width": '5px'}, 1000);
    $("#pastebox").animate({"border-width": '0px'}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pastebox" />
```

Console is always helpful.

Comment: This is perfect and i've got it working.  Unfortunately its not the effect I was hoping for.  Any quick tip on how I might get it so that the border expands around the outside of the box, while the box stays the same size?

Comment: Sure, set the initial padding of 5px, and then animate it down as you animate the border up, and vice-versa.